# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined reactjs url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

```
 //     }
  71 | // }
  72 | render () {
> 73 |  const email = this.props.params.username;
     | ^  74 |    console.log(email);
  75 |  const data = this.state;
  76 |  return (
```

```
const click = this.state.click ? '/'+this.state.user_email+'/'+this.state.id : '';
<Link to={click} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
<Route exact path='/:uid?/:username?' component={Profile} />
```

Please help
I am new to react
I am passing email and id through URL and trying to access in another component.

Iam just want to pass email and id through URL and want to access in other class component.

Comment: That means that `this.props.params` is undefined... may I see what you're doing with this.props.params?

Comment: Try this - `path='/:uid/:username'`

Comment: Just displaying